# IEC Connector Pinouts

Tags: power, connector

Is this the correct convention for providing power to IEC cables/connectors in USA?

[image]

If your immediate reaction is "google it", I'm finding many diagrams online use somewhat ambiguous drawings instead of actual pictures of these things. It seems the "plug/pins/male" and "receptacle/sockets/female" words are often used incorrectly or it's unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The star indicates the N may be Hot with L2 while L is always Line.

[image]

Comment: This only works if the other end of the cable has a polarized connector, too. E.g. *Schuko* isn't, and it's the most used "other end".

Comment: That's another meaning for the star for 50Hz bipolar plugs

Comment: What I meant is these IEC connectors, when used in the US, have both outer contacts hot in 230V applications. And when they are used in Europe, the user may use an IEC/Schuko cable, so any of the two outer pins may be hot.

Comment: So the Hot can actually be neutral?  the reverse was my statement

Comment: Yes, whereever Schuko outlets and plugs are in use, you can reverse the plug in those, and then L and N on the connected IEC plug also reverse.

Comment: I wonder if that poses flicker issues for some luminaires with dimmers and triacs with weaker quadrants, such that reversing the plug fixes it or reduces hum in audio systems?

Comment: @Janka: US cables for IEC connectors are always grounded, which makes them polarized unless modified.

Answer (score 2):

Devices with these IEC connectors **must not** make any assumptions about hot and neutral. In U.S. 230V applications, both are hot anyway, as the U.S. uses a split-phase for creating 115V+115V from 230V.

The longer middle pin is ground.

Comment: US 230v applications don't use typically use that plug.

Comment: Oh? Better not export the device to Europe then.

Comment: In theory it should be connected like the OP posted but you are right that those devices should work safely both ways since some places (even in Europe) have 230V between fases (so N might be "hot" as well) and lots of wall sockets can be plugged both way (except French and UK). In Belgium we use the French type which can only be plugged one way but our regulations do not enforce which pin is neutral or line.

Answer (score 1):

In Europe the two power pins can both be actives (hots) in a 3 phase system, with 220 or 230 volts between each phase.  Norway still uses this in many residential and rural areas, with 230 / 400 volt systems in newer and industrial areas, as much of the rest of Europe. Italy used 220 volts for power (between actives) and 127 (active to neutral) for lights, with different tarrifs.